# Getting white flash animation effect upon clicking play and pause buttons

Tags: ios

I have a single button toggling between play and pause for audio playback. When I was using the standard play/pause buttons (e.g., initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay), I got a nice white flash animation effect over the buttons as they toggled back and forth. But now that I am using custom images, I no longer get that effect. How can I get it back?

Also would very much appreciate any tips to simplify this as it seems heavyweight. I saw https://stackoverflow.com/a/9104587/1462372 but am not clear whether that is applicable in this case (in button bar).

Here is the code:

```
- (void) setAsPlaying:(BOOL)isPlaying
{
    self.rootViewController.playing = isPlaying;

    // we need to change which of play/pause buttons are showing, if the one to
    // reverse current action isn't showing
    if ((isPlaying && !self.pauseButton) || (!isPlaying && !self.playButton))
    {
        UIBarButtonItem *buttonToRemove = nil;
        UIBarButtonItem *buttonToAdd = nil;
        if (isPlaying)
        {
            buttonToRemove = self.playButton;
            self.playButton = nil;

            UIImage *pauseButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_pause.png"];
            UIButton *pauseButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [pauseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pauseAudio:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            pauseButton.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, pauseButtonImage.size.width, pauseButtonImage.size.height);
            [pauseButton setImage:pauseButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            self.pauseButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:pauseButton];
            buttonToAdd = self.pauseButton;
        }
        else
        {
            buttonToRemove = self.pauseButton;
            self.pauseButton = nil;

// this was the way I was doing it before:
//            self.playButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay target:self action:@selector(playAudio:)];

            UIImage *playButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_play.png"];
            UIButton *playButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playAudio:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            playButton.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, playButtonImage.size.width, playButtonImage.size.height);
            [playButton setImage:playButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            self.playButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:playButton];
            buttonToAdd = self.playButton;
        }

        // Get the reference to the current toolbar buttons
        NSMutableArray *toolbarButtons = [[self.toolbar items] mutableCopy];

        // Remove a button from the toolbar and add the other one
        if (buttonToRemove)
            [toolbarButtons removeObject:buttonToRemove];
        if (![toolbarButtons containsObject:buttonToAdd])
            [toolbarButtons insertObject:buttonToAdd atIndex:5];

        [self.toolbar setItems:toolbarButtons];
    }
}
```

Comment: check out my code....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code might be helpful to you...

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook.png"];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height-10);
UIButton *rightbtnItem = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

[rightbtnItem setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[rightbtnItem setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
```

Comment: Simple and Easy way ....!! Point is you will have to set background image of button. If you set foreground image you could not see the effect ....

Comment: this works fine for me.. and i think this is very simple way to the effect on button..

Comment: yeah I have also tested it.Working fine

Comment: Thanks. Including the `addTarget` line, this is same number of lines of code as I had, but maybe a little simpler. Either way, the key line for the glow effect is `[button setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];`. That worked even when added to my original code.

Comment: Also, I assume that `image.size.height-10` is specific to your image - it was clipping mine so I removed the `-10`.

Comment: mowliv it's depend upon the imagesize if your image is proper then no need to image.size.height-10;

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste it in your viewDidload and see glow effect on touch.

```
UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ar.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
button.center=self.view.center;
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"RS2kQ.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Get Image from here [ar.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uo3d0.png)  and [RS2kQ.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1HU9.png)